# Backbone.js set URL parameters in model & use it with fetch

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I would like to fetch model from specific url with parameter:
url: server/somecontroller/id/?type=gift

Simple working way is:

```
collection.fetch({ data: { type: 'gift'} });
```

But I want to set it in model:

```
    ...
    if(id){
      App.coupon = new AffiliatesApp.Coupon({id: id});
    } else {
      App.coupon = new AffiliatesApp.Coupon({id: 'somecontroller'}, {type: 'gift'});
    }
    App.coupon.fetch();
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to override Backbone's [url](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) method on the Coupon model with one defined by you. For example you can do :

```
Affiliates.Coupon = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot : "server/somecontroller/",
  url : function(){
    var url = this.urlRoot + this.id;
    if(this.get("type")){
      url = url + "/?type=" + this.get("type");
    }
    return url;
  }
});
```

This solution is easy to implement but has a drawback: the generated URL will be used for every action that syncs to the server (fetch,save,..).

If you need to have a finer control over the generation of the URL depending on what action you are doing you will need to override Backbone's [Sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) method for your model.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by overriding the fetch method in model to use some custom data. Using [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) it could look like this:

```
class AffiliatesApp.Coupon extends Backbone.Model
  fetch: ->
    super(data: { type: @get('type') })
```

Note that this example will ignore any attributes passed to `coupon.fetch()`, however it can be easily adjusted for any override logic.